# Public Key pinning with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, pinning

I want to implement public key pinning with NSURLSession. From various posts i am getting certificate pinning but not any solid reference for public key pinning. I don't want to use certificate pinning to avoid future update in server side certificate and my app release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit . It's an iOS library that makes it easy to do public key pinning, and it works with NSURLSession.

Comment: Looks great  TrustKit uses PublicKeyHashes, what is difference between public key and kTSKPublicKeyHashes

Comment: The library pins something called the subject public key info (SPKI). It's the public key + the key's algorithm (RSA, ECDSA, etc.). It's the safest way to implement pinning (see https://www.imperialviolet.org/2011/05/04/pinning.html ).